# Can't receive Fire-base notification when the app open

Tags: android, firebase

I am making an android app that receives notifications. I can receive the notification when the app is closed or in the background, but I can't receive it when the app is open and even look like it isn't going through onMessageReceived Method. what do I need to add or edit?
Here is the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="saleh.example.trail">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"

        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>



        <activity
            android:name=".Products_List"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_products__list"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Categories"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_categories"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignIn"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_in"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firbase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/bisc" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
    </application   >

</manifest>
```

Also here is MyFirebaseMessagingService code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d("Noti: ", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
                Toast.makeText(this,"message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds

                Toast.makeText(this,"No message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.d("Token",s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FCM there are two kinds of message: Notification and Data. But the main difference is that Notifications are displayed in the notification tray, while Datas are not.
You must send data notification and show received message by notification manager.
this code can help you:

```
 @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    //        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    //        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();



            createNotification(remoteMessage);


            }



        private void createNotification(RemoteMessage messageBody) {


            PushModel pushModel=new PushModel() ;

    //        pushModel = new Gson().fromJson(messageBody,PushModel.class);
           try {

               pushModel.setBody(messageBody.getData().get("body"));
               pushModel.setTitle(messageBody.getData().get("title"));
    //           pushModel = convertJsonToBaseApiModel(messageBody);
           }catch (Exception e){
               String s = e.getMessage();
           }


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AppController.getPreferenceModel().setNotifMessage(pushModel.getBody());
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
            PendingIntent resultIntents = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            String channelId = "Dialog";

            Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_ansar_logo)
                    .setContentTitle(pushModel.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(pushModel.getBody())
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)

    //                .addAction(R.drawable.filter_outline, "Hello", resultIntents)
    //                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_alert, "Call", resultIntent)
                    .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setWhen(0)
                    .setContentIntent(resultIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                        "Channel human readable title",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());

        }





        public static PushModel convertJsonToBaseApiModel(String json) {


            String testTitle=json.substring(json.indexOf("title="),json.indexOf(","));

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).setLenient()
                    .create();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<PushModel>() {
            }.getType();
           PushModel pushModel = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
            return pushModel;
        }
```